# Captcha validation fails with the rating form

Tags: solspace-rating, captcha

I just installed Solspace Rating module and included the rating form like this:

```
{exp:rating:form entry_id="{entry_id}" allow_duplicates="no" anonymous="yes" collection="neueroeffnungen" return="bewertung_danke"}
    {if not_duplicate}
        {if logged_out}
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value='Guest_{current_time format="%U"}' />
        {/if}

        <select name="rating" id="rating">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>

        {if captcha}
            {captcha}
        {/if}

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Rate" />
    {/if}
{/exp:rating:form}
```

It works great if I don't require a captcha, but if I do, I always get:

> The captcha you submitted is incorrect.

Any idea what I'm missing?

EE v2.8.1 - Build: 20140314
Solspace Rating 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the module preferences here:

Modules > Rating > Preferences

Use Captcha? set to "yes"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the captcha input, where the value for validation should go.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" autocomplete="off" size="20" required />
```

And as far I have some experience with Solspace products you should check what expression they are using for captcha. 
For example if you're using freeform - it is something like:

```
  {exp:freeform:captcha}
```

or something.